# Customizer Issue, Default Settings not working

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a class for handling customizer code, where I am adding a lot of color options. I have trimmed a bunch of repetitive parts out so it is not too long ;) My issue is I cannot figure out why the default settings do not appear to be being set, but only on front end. If I open in the customizer view, the live preview is correct, the defaults are working, however on the front end view it is not. If I change a value in the customizer to hit save/publish, then the front end looks right. So this leads me to think the defaults are not being set like I think they are, hoping for some help figuring out why. Thank you.

```
final class showcase_Custom_Colors {

private static $instance;

public function __construct() {

    /* Output CSS into <head>. */
    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'wp_head_callback' ) );

    /* Add options to the theme customizer. */
    add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'customize_register' ) );
}

public function wp_head_callback() {

    $stylesheet = get_stylesheet();

    /* Get the cached style. */
    $style = wp_cache_get( "{$stylesheet}_custom_colors" );

    /* If the style is available, output it and return. */
    if ( !empty( $style ) ) {
        echo $style;
        return;
    }

    $style = $this->get_primary_color();
    $style .= $this->get_secondary_color();
    $style .= $this->get_copy_color();
    $style .= $this->get_headings_color();

    /* Put the final style output together. */
    $style = "\n" . '<style type="text/css" id="custom-colors-css">' . trim( $style ) . '</style>' . "\n";

    /* Cache the style, so we don't have to process this on each page load. */
    wp_cache_set( "{$stylesheet}_custom_colors", $style );

    /* Output the custom style. */
    echo $style;
}


public function editor_styles_callback() {

    header( 'Content-type: text/css' );

    echo $this->get_primary_color();
    echo $this->get_secondary_color();
    echo $this->get_copy_color();
    echo $this->get_headings_color();

    die();
}

/* Primary color */
public function get_primary_color() {
    $style = '';
    $hex = get_theme_mod( 'color_primary', '' );
    $rgb = join( ', ', hybrid_hex_to_rgb( $hex ) );
    $style .= "
            a,
            .page-numbers,
            .color-primary,
            legend,
            mark,
            .comment-respond .required,
            pre,
            code,
            .form-allowed-tags code,
            pre code {
                color: #{$hex};
            }";
    $style .= "
            code,
            legend,
            mark,
            pre,
            .form-allowed-tags code {
                background-color: rgba( {$rgb}, 0.1 );
            }";
    $style .= "
            blockquote {
                border-color: rgba( {$rgb}, 0.85 );
            }";
    return str_replace( array( "\r", "\n", "\t" ), '', $style );
}

public function customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    // Add panel for colors
    $wp_customize->add_panel( 'site_colors', array(
        'title'                     => 'Site Colors',
        'description'           => 'Color options for the site',
    ) );

    // Defines sections for each color area in an array
    $color_sections = array(
        'global_colors' => array(
            'priority'      => 5,
            'title'             => 'Global Colors',
            'description'   => 'Colors used in various locations'
            ),
        'header_colors' => array(
            'priority'      => 10,
            'title'             => 'Header Colors',
            'description'   => 'Colors used in the site header'
            ),
    );

    // Defines settings for each color
    $color_settings = array(
        'color_primary'         => '3855a0',
        'color_secondary'       => 'e09088',
        'color_copy'            => '4a4a4a',
        'color_headings'        => '3a3a3a',
    );

    // Add each color section from array above
    foreach ( $color_sections as $color_section_id => $color_args ) {

        $wp_customize->add_section(
            $color_section_id,
            array(
                'priority'      => $color_args['priority'],
                'panel'             => 'site_colors',
                'title'             => $color_args['title'],
                'description'   => $color_args['description'],
            )
        );
    }

    // Add each color setting from array above
    foreach ( $color_settings as $color_setting_id => $color_setting_default ) {

        $wp_customize->add_setting(
            $color_setting_id,
            array(
                'default'               => $color_setting_default,
                'transport'             => 'postMessage',
                'sanitize_callback'     => 'sanitize_hex_color_no_hash',
                'sanitize_js_callback'  => 'maybe_hash_hex_color',
                )
            );
    }

    /* Add a control for this color. */
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'custom-colors-primary',
            array(
                'label'     => esc_html__( 'Primary Color', 'showcase' ),
                'section'   => 'global_colors',
                'settings'  => 'color_primary',
                'priority'  => 5,
            )
        ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'custom-colors-secondary',
            array(
                'label'     => esc_html__( 'Secondary Color', 'showcase' ),
                'section'   => 'global_colors',
                'settings'  => 'color_secondary',
                'priority'  => 10,
            )
        ) );

    // Lots more....

}

public static function get_instance() {

    if ( !self::$instance )
        self::$instance = new self;

    return self::$instance;
}
}

showcase_Custom_Colors::get_instance();
```

Clarification code sample:

```
add_filter( 'theme_mod_color_primary', array( $this, 'color_primary_default' ), 95 );
public function color_primary_default( $hex ) {
    return $hex ? $hex : 'e74c3c';
}
```

Comment: yeap, thanks alot, i did not check the codex. this cost me many hours. the get_theme_mod second parameter must be specified. but is there no way to use the "default" of $wp_customizer->add_setting() to set the default to apply for get_theme_mod() ?

Comment: @user93380 No, there is no way to do that because they have different purposes.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different defaults, and you're only using one of them.

The default value that you set in the call to $wp_customize->add_setting is the default *for the customizer*. It does not apply outside of the customizer. The default here is what will be used if no setting exists in the database.

The second default is in the get_theme_mod call, and here you're using a blank value as the default. You need to use the proper default value as the second argument to get_theme_mod.

Comment: AAAHHHHAAAA! Thank you, I did not realize there were two different defaults. That makes much more sense now. I added a second code sample, this code was built based on Justin Tadlock's, and he had a filter/function that set defaults. Is that what causes the setting default to work his way? The call to get_theme_mod activated the filter function correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your customizer code is Correct so the backend will work Fine but for the front-end you made a very small mistake.

get_theme_mod uses two parameter First your Setting declared parameter and Second Default Value. So Just change following link:

```
$hex = get_theme_mod( 'color_primary', 'default_color_value' );
```

'default_color_value' as your hex color code value.

I know you have solved this issue but I wrote this answer just because to make it beginner-friendly. Like Me :)